# Populate images via JS in lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, lightbox2

I'm using this [Image Gallery Plugin](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery). I need to populate the Images via JavaScript. I tried some methods. But it is not working.

Can someone suggest me a way to `populate Images` via `JavaScript.`

```js
var img1 = "https://picsum.photos/600.jpg?image=251";
var img2 = "https://picsum.photos/600.jpg?image=252";
var img3 = "https://picsum.photos/600.jpg?image=253";

var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
c1.src = img1;
```

```html
<div class="example" id="exampleZoomGallery" style="display: flex;">
  <a class="inline-block" href="../../global/img/heart.jpg" title="view-7" data-source="../../global/img/heart.jpg">
    <img id="c1" class="img-responsive" src="../../global/img/heart.jpg" alt="..." width="220" style="padding: 5px;" />
  </a>
  <a class="inline-block" href="../../global/img/heart.jpg" title="view-8" data-source="../../global/img/heart.jpg">
    <img id="c2" class="img-responsive" src="../../global/img/heart.jpg" alt="..." width="220" style="padding: 5px;" />
  </a>
  <a class="inline-block" href="../../global/img/heart.jpg" title="view-9" data-source="../../global/img/heart.jpg">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../../global/img/heart.jpg" alt="..." width="220" style="padding: 5px;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is happening when you do this? `src = img1;` ? Also, how come the src attribute is already set in your html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/weazk35f/22/

Create a container to place your images in...

```
<div class="example" id="exampleZoomGallery" style="display: flex;"></div>
```

then store all of the images in an array and get a reference to the container...

```
var images = [
    'https://picsum.photos/600.jpg?image=251',
    'https://picsum.photos/600.jpg?image=252',
    'https://picsum.photos/600.jpg?image=253'
];

var gallery = jQuery('#exampleZoomGallery');
```

Next create a function to populate an image...

```
function populateImage(src, container) {
    var a = jQuery('<a></a>');
    a.attr('href', src);
    a.attr('data-toggle', 'lightbox');

    // Optional but allows for navigation between images within lightbox
    a.attr('data-gallery', container.attr('id'));

    var img = jQuery('<img />');
    img.attr('src', src);

    a.append(img);
    container.append(a);
}
```

and finally iterate over each of the images in your array when the DOM is ready and initialize your lightbox plugin

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(images).each(function(index, image) {
        populateImage(image, gallery);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
});
```

Comment: Image is populating. But in Onclick it is not showing in light box ?

Comment: Are you referring to the onClick event not working in your code or the jsfiddle example? If it's your code could you post where you've implemented the 'click' handler?

Comment: I'm referring to jsFiddle example ?

Comment: My bad - I've updated the jsfiddle link with a more up to date example. Could you try again?

Comment: Thank You! But I was unable to get the gallery arrows in the side ?

Comment: Have updated my answer and the jsfiddle example. Each <a> tag just needs the 'data-gallery' attribute to be the same. In the example I've reused the 'id' attribute from the container (i.e 'exampleZoomGallery')

Comment: How Can i replace with this plugin dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html ?